# Clean update/install of new Android version (non-nexus)

Tags: updates, ota-update, motorola-moto-g2

- I don't have a Nexus device (I have a Moto G2 2013).
- Today I received the OTA update from my manufacturer (6.0 Marshmallow).

I want to do a clean install/update on my device. For example, when upgrading Windows it asks me if I want a clean install. I found out Android doesn't give me the option.

**What is the cleanest way to upgrade my device?**

1. Factory reset my device (going back to 4.4) and then hop versions (OTA to 5.0 and then 6.0)?
2. Look for an ISO from my manufacturer and flash it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a factory reset would revert your device back to 4.4, I'm pretty sure it would still be on 6.0. A factory reset would wipe all user data on your device without touching the OS.

If you some want to wipe all installed apps (bar system apps) and user data then a factory reset would do. If you want to wipe the OS too then you would need to find a full device image.

Comment: Confirmed: Factory reset *never* touches `/system`, so it *definitely* wouldn't "go back to 4.4". See our [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) for details ;) So yes: A clean install would be doing a factory-reset followed by flashing a "full image".

Comment: You don't need to remove the apps first, a factory reset will take care of them.  A factory reset + the X-to-Y upgrade should be identical to a clean install of the full ROM for Y.